# How do you know how many states are needed for a finite automata?

Tags: theory, finite-automata

I have included a picture regarding my question. So for this question it says to make an FA that accepts a string that begins/ends with aa or bb. My question is how do you know when to stop adding states? Like why wouldn't 5 states be enough instead of the 9 shown?

[image: Finite automata]

Comment: Have you tried constructing a DFA for this language with five states? If you believe it should be possible, the first thing to do is try it.

Answer (score 0):

Given a formal description of the language, we could translate it to a finite state automaton algorithmically, and there must be an algorithm that finds the smallest automaton (by enumeration if nothing else, since the possibilities are finite). However, given a natural language description, we do not (yet) have algorithms to translate it into an automaton or other formal description.

However, in this case we can reason:

- The states after seeing “”, “a”, and “b” must be distinct, as the consequences of them vary depending on whether the next character is “a” or “b”. (“a” followed by “a” is accepted whereas “b” followed by “a” is not [yet] accepted. And “a” followed by “a” is accepted whereas “” followed by “a” is not [yet], and so on.)
- The two states reached by “aa” and “bb” are identical and can be coalesced, reducing the automaton to eight states.
- Otherwise, after seeing “ab” or “ba” initially, we must have distinct states for:

  - The last characters seen were “aa”. (This state must be accepted if it is the end state, and it must lead to itself [or an isomorphic state] if an “a” is received but a different state if a “b” is received.)
  - The last characters seen were “bb”. (Analogous to above but swapping what happens if “a” or “b” is received.)
  - The last characters seen were “ab”. (This state must lead to the “bb”-was-last-seen state if a “b” is received but not if an “a” is received.)
  - The last characters seen were “ba”. (Analogous to above but swapped.)
- Those four states must also be distinct from the initial four states:

  - The initial “a“ state and the initial “b” state must lead to acceptance no matter what else is received, whereas none of the later four states may do that.
  - The initial “” state cannot lead to acceptance after one more letter, whereas the later four states all do if the appropriate letter is received.
  - The state for having seen “aa” or “bb” at the start must lead only to acceptance, whereas none of the later four states may lead to unconditional acceptance.

Thus, we must have eight states.

Comment: *"there must be an algorithm that finds the smallest automaton (by enumeration if nothing else, since the possibilities are finite)"* Minor quibble with this - there is an algorithm for checking whether two DFAs recognise the same language, but it uses an algorithm for minimising a DFA as a subroutine, so you wouldn't be able to construct the latter using the former as a subroutine unless you have an alternative way of checking whether two DFAs recognise the same language, which doesn't start by minimising both of them.

Comment: In other contexts, finding the smallest program with a particular behaviour can't be done by exhaustive search, because it's undecidable whether two programs have the same behaviour. So the quoted sentence isn't exactly wrong, but it could be misleading since it doesn't make clear that it relies on the equivalence problem being decidable for DFAs.

Comment: In addition to @kaya3's excellent points, *"since the possibilities are finite"* is also erroneous as any given infinite language has infinite possible accepting DFAs by way of expanding loops. In OP's example, the terminal, self-looping accepting states (representing strings starting with "aa" and "bb") can be expanded indefinitely into arbitrarily long chains (or loops!) of accepting states. This is true of any language whose minimal DFA features a loop (i.e., infinite regular languages).

Comment: @Welbog: The existence of infinitely many DFAs for the language is irrelevant. The possibilities we are considering are just those that are smaller than the one we start with, of which there are a finite number.

Comment: @kaya3: There are a number of algorithms that test equivalence without minimizing the DFAs. (A survey of some is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67655699/how-do-you-know-how-many-states-are-needed-for-a-finite-automata/67655775#comment119584651_67655775).). Minimization is not the main point of the answer, so I do not think it is worth embellishing. As for excluding other contexts, I think the context is sufficiently established by the fact the title asks about finite automata, the question is tagged finite-automata, and the answer mentions a finite state automaton.